# No menu on Chrome and Edge browsers? How to open a local file or see history?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

There is no menu bar on my Chrome and Edge browsers. Sometimes I need to open a local html file, or check out history. Now I have no menu to get them done. Have The two browsers canceled the traditional menu bar which appears on the top of almost all window applications?

Comment: On what OS are you experiencing this?

Comment: On Windows 11 @HarmManders

Comment: Which version of Edge and Chrome are you using? Could you please provide screenshots about the issue in Edge and Chrome? I checked my Edge and Chrome and they have menu bars, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1s66.png.